# Camera intent result image size

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-camera-intent

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

I am taking picture through this. I am able to get the camera picture from onActivityResult

I need the picture size to be smaller ( custom defined if possible )

That is the camera app should give me an image of 2MP( Mega Pixel wise) OR some 726 KB ( Size wise) output.

any Camera.putExtra will work for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [`EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT), I haven't tried it though - reading other answers seems this does **not** work with that particular action.

Otherwise, a simple solution would be to specify the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` location for the image, then on the receive to sample that image down to an appropriate file size.

Also maybe you should take a look at [this project on github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) that attempts to handle all the problems in capturing an image, which seems to give the ability to control picture size.

Comment: I ll try..no specific documentation for these things?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
public class ScalingUtilities {

    /**
     * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
     * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
     * and scaling logic.
     *
     * @param res The resources object containing the image data
     * @param resId The resource id of the image data
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Decoded bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Utility function for creating a scaled version of an existing bitmap
     *
     * @param unscaledBitmap Bitmap to scale
     * @param dstWidth Wanted width of destination bitmap
     * @param dstHeight Wanted height of destination bitmap
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return New scaled bitmap object
     */
    public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
     * destination image has different aspect ratio.
     *
     * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
     * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
     * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
     *
     * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
     * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
     * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
     * requested.
     */
    public static enum ScalingLogic {
        CROP, FIT
    }

    /**
     * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
     * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
     */
    public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates source rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal source rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
                final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
                return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
            } else {
                final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
                final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
                return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates destination rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal destination rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
            } else {
                return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
        }
    }

}
```